# How to embed a custom tableViewController to other viewControllers

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I wrote a custom tableViewController class named as timeLineController. Also I created a tableViewController in storyboard whose class is timeLineController. How can I properly embed this controller to other viewControllers. I want to pass data to tableView and call tableView.reloadData() method, when viewDidLoad() method of the viewController is called.

Comment: Include some code to show what you have been trying to achieve your goal.

Answer (score 1):

I resolve the issue by defining a class variable in the viewController:

```
    let timeLineController =  TimelineController(nibName: "TimelineController", bundle: nil);
```

And in the viewDidLoad() method of the viewController I add timeLineController as a childViewController:

```
    timeLineController.view.frame = myTimeLineFrame
    timeLineController.data = timeLineData
    self.addChildViewController(timeLineController);
    timeLineController.didMoveToParentViewController(self)
```